# MVC Application redirecting to ReturnUrl=%2f when i start my app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

My MVC app is redirecting to http ://local host:53550/Projects/Index?ReturnUrl=%2f? when i start my app.
I want my startup url should be http ://local host:53550/Projects/Index.
I dont want ?ReturnUrl=%2f? to be appended.

This is my webconfig:

```
  <forms loginUrl="Projects/Index" timeout="180" domain="" name="myApplicationCookie"  path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="~/"/>

</authentication>


<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>

</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try swapping them around.

**Example**

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

`<deny users="?" />` denies anonymous users.

`<allow users="*" />` allow access all user accounts.

Having `deny` last will overrule the `allow`.  But if these are public pages and not behind an authentication barrier then you should either remove or modify the `deny`.